# Is it permissible to pray on the sand at a beach or on the grass at a park?

Tags: salat

I like to stay healthy and one way I do that is by walking or running. Sometimes it would be convenient to do prayer just wherever I happen to be.

**Question**: Is it permissible to pray on the sand at a beach or on the grass at a park?

As I understand, I don't need to worry if people see me pray. But I'm not sure if praying on sand or on a patch of grass meets the condition of a clean place to pray.

Some Google hits suggest it's okay (e.g. [this](http://www.islamicity.com/forum/printer_friendly_posts.asp?TID=21523)), but they're random people on forums.

Comment: Is the question about najasa (ritual impurities) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is according to Shia fiqh but I guess it must be shared by other juridical schools since I have seen Sunnis praying on grass. So, yes! It's OK so far as there is no clear indication that the surface is najis. And be wary of manure in grass; it might not be najis, but it's recommended to pray on the cleanest of grounds and environments.

But as for sand, you must wipe your forehead clean after each prostration. The surface must also not be too uneven (four-fingers-width altitude at most between the kneeling spot and the prostration spot).

I could think of one reservation though as for beach. I don't think it is dignified to pray in a place where men and women mix while naked which is grossly un-Islamic (unless you go to segregated beaches). In fact it is even sinful *to be present* in such a place, a ruling that may a priori invalidate any deeds performed therein.

Peaceful prayers!