# Praying in a room where a dog has been

Tags: salat

Asalaam alaykum. I have had my dog inside my home for nearly 14 years and it has came into my room before. I was not raised in a practicing Muslim household until a few years ago I decided to begin practicing by praying and fasting etc. I pray in a room that the dog didn’t go into often but has been in. Is it ok if I pray in my own room if my floor is clean or if I put a rug down and my prayer mat on top of that? I know the rulings of a wet dog or the saliva of a dog touching me, but I would prefer to pray in my own room if I can (of course with the dog not in my room) What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your prayer mat is clean it is fine to pray on. If you want to pray on a clean surface but your room is dirty just use the prayer mat and then pray on it. This link may be beneficial too: [What dirty (but ritually clean) surfaces can you pray on?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46756/what-dirty-but-ritually-clean-surfaces-can-you-pray-on)